# Seafile 10 on Docker permission denied for entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, seafile-server

```
Attaching to seafile, seafile-memcached, seafile-mysql
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 00:36:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 started.
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 00:36:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user ‘mysql’
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 00:36:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 started.
seafile-mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 453: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 00:36:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 00:36:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
seafile-mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 136: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.12-MariaDB-1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 source revision 4c79e15cc3716f69c044d4287ad2160da8101cdc as process 47
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Can’t create/write to file ‘/tmp/ibzKUuDI’ (Errcode: 13 “Permission denied”)
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Can’t create/write to file ‘/tmp/ibEQRyhJ’ (Errcode: 13 “Permission denied”)
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown…
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ init function returned error.
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [Note] Plugin ‘FEEDBACK’ is disabled.
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
seafile-mysql | 2023-06-16 0:36:31 0 [ERROR] Aborting
seafile | *** Running /etc/my_init.d/01_create_data_links.sh…
seafile | *** Booting runit daemon…
seafile | *** Runit started as PID 24
seafile | *** Running /scripts/enterpoint.sh…
seafile | 2023-06-16 00:36:31 Nginx ready
seafile | 2023-06-16 00:36:31 This is an idle script (infinite loop) to keep container running.
seafile-mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 136: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
seafile-mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 136: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
seafile-mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 136: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
```

suddenly docker doesn’t have permissions for these files, i tried chmod 777 and 1777 on the directories but no result

Comment: Show your compose file by editing the question. Use named volumes for data.